# How can I ignore binary caches when running nix-channel commands?

Tags: nixos, nix

Quite often, I'm away from home where I have a binary cache set for `192.168.0.6` and I run into errors like so:

```
sudo nix-channel --update
unpacking channels...
warning: unable to download 'http://192.168.0.6:8899/nix-cache-info': Couldn't connect to server (7); retrying in 305 ms
warning: unable to download 'http://192.168.0.6:8899/nix-cache-info': Couldn't connect to server (7); retrying in 693 ms
warning: unable to download 'http://192.168.0.6:8899/nix-cache-info': Couldn't connect to server (7); retrying in 1021 ms
warning: unable to download 'http://192.168.0.6:8899/nix-cache-info': Couldn't connect to server (7); retrying in 2429 ms
warning: unable to download 'http://192.168.0.6:8899/nix-cache-info': Couldn't connect to server (7)
^Cerror: interrupted by the user
```

How can I remove/ignore this?

---

I'm not able to rebuild my config due to:

It seems there is an option of `nixos-rebuild switch --fallback --show-trace --option binary-caches https://cache.nixos.org/ forced`  (found here https://github.com/NixOS/nix/issues/1990#issuecomment-377969731)

However as I'm referencing an `unstable` channel in my config, it fails:

```
building Nix...
building the system configuration...
error: file 'unstable' was not found in the Nix search path (add it using $NIX_PATH or -I), at /etc/nixos/chris.nix:25:21
(use '--show-trace' to show detailed location information)
```